# Why is rmarkdown rounding columns based on number of digits of smallest value?

Tags: r, r-markdown, digits, kable

I have a data frame with two numeric columns. I am trying to make different data frames by selecting based on conditions and output them in an rmarkdown html document rounded to two decimal places by setting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, options(digits=2))` and printing the table using `kable` however this is not working as expected. I also tried using `options(scipen=1, digits=2)` based on previous solutions to similar questions.

If the smallest number in the column is >=10 and <99 it rounds the entire column to the nearest whole number. (10.931 becomes 11)

If the smallest number is >=1 and <10 it rounds to one decimal. (1.0931 becomes 1.1)

I can only achieve two decimal places if the smallest number is less than 1, and when the smallest number is <0.1 I still only get two decimal places. (0.010931 becomes 0.01). This is not a problem for me as I only want two decimal places, but I am sure it is related to the issue I am having so thought I would include it.

The number of digits is based on the smallest number in the column, but applied to the entire column. How can I make it so that all numbers contain two decimal places?

Comment: To set a custom number of decimal places in `kable()` output, you can use the `digits` argument within the `kable` function.

Comment: @eipi10 is there a way to do this globally so I don't have to do it every time?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `options(digits=2)` (on its own line, not inside `knitr::opts_chunk$set`) sets the number of digits globally, since `kable` gets its default number of digits from this option (you can see this in the help for `kable`).

However, the `digits` argument is passed to the `round` function, which will when possible round to a lower number of decimal places than the `digits` value.

As far as I know, if you want to guarantee a specific number of digits, you need to use `sprintf` (there may be other options that I'm not aware of). Even `format` doesn't guarantee a specific number of decimal places (the help says: `"The default, NULL, uses getOption("digits"). This is a suggestion: enough decimal places will be used so that the smallest (in magnitude) number has this many significant digits, and also to satisfy nsmall"`).

Here are some examples:

```r
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

d = tibble(x=c(1,15,99,101,1001))
kable(d)
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 15 |
| 99 |
| 101 |
| 1001 |

```r
options(digits=2)
kable(d)
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 15 |
| 99 |
| 101 |
| 1001 |

```r
d = tibble(x=c(1.5495389,15,99,101,1001.152))
kable(d)
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1.6 |
| 15.0 |
| 99.0 |
| 101.0 |
| 1001.1 |

```r
options(digits=3)
kable(d)
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1.55 |
| 15.00 |
| 99.00 |
| 101.00 |
| 1001.15 |

```r
options(digits=7)
kable(d)
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1.549539 |
| 15.000000 |
| 99.000000 |
| 101.000000 |
| 1001.152000 |

```r
# format function
d %>% 
  mutate(x = format(x, digits=4)) %>% 
  kable(align="r")
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1.55 |
| 15.00 |
| 99.00 |
| 101.00 |
| 1001.15 |

```r
# sprintf function
d %>% 
  mutate(x = sprintf("%1.4f", x)) %>% 
  kable(align="r")
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1.5495 |
| 15.0000 |
| 99.0000 |
| 101.0000 |
| 1001.1520 |

```r
# sprintf function
d %>% 
  mutate(x = sprintf("%1.10f", x)) %>% 
  kable(align="r")
```

| x |
| --- |
| 1.5495389000 |
| 15.0000000000 |
| 99.0000000000 |
| 101.0000000000 |
| 1001.1520000000 |

<sup>Created on 2021-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>